# modal dialog - bootstrap for ember

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog

I want to bind the modal to links to show the content - where the link points - in a modal.
I use Bootstrap-for-ember https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember.

The idea, that every time when a route visited the function "activate" runs. I placed here the the modal's init.

The problem: If i close the modal, and click again the same link, the activate function wont run again, and the modal doesnt initializate, only if i click an another link and back again.

I made a simple JsBin setup http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/29/edit to demonstrate the problem.
Click "Settings", close the modal, then again "Settings", then "Dashboard" and "Settings" again.

Maybe the whole concept is wrong an there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you fire the open method of the modal in the 'activate' method of the route, which is only called when you enter the route from another non-child route, but at the first click you enter the SettingsRoute, and stay there, such that the second click is moving from SettingsRoute to itself - so 'activate' is not called.

There are 2 sensible solutions:
1) when closing the modal, route back to the parent route (index)
2) don't use routes to open the modal - just use actions to open it in the parent route.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you! i updated the JsBin with with solution 1: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/39/edit . but i have no idea how to handle the closing with x (upper right corner).

Comment: seems like bootstrap-for-ember had added a "closed" event for the modal. Try using it.

Comment: unfortuneatly i couldnt figure out how to use closed event. The main problem i dont know how get my modal instance. Then i guess it would be instance.on('closed',function(){console.log('modal closed')}); can u please give me some advice? or show on my JsBin? thanks

Comment: not very familiar with this implementation. My best guess would be that the open method should return a reference to the modal, as it is the one that instantiates it.

Comment: i have just saw, that i forgot to share the working jsbin: the http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EveQOke/189